# Using malloc to allocate an array of NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Since NSSstring is not defined in length like integer or double, do I run the risk of problems allocating an array of NSStrings for it using malloc?

thanks

ie:

```
NSString ***nssName;
nssName = (NSString***) malloc(iN * sizeof(NSString*));
```

the end result with for_loops for the rows is a 2D array, so it is a little easier to work then NSArray(less code).

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to allocate an `NSString` or and array with pointers to `NSString`s ?

Comment: Use NSArray;  it'll be easier to maintain and the transition to ARC will be much simpler, too.   The "less code" argument falls flat in the face of the additional maintenance cost.

Comment: The end result of that code is not a 2D array. It's decidedly one-dimensional.

Comment: Your revised code still doesn't constitute a valid 2D array. You need to allocate one dimension, then loop through that dimension creating the other dimension for each index in the first dimension. Just like you would with a 2D NSArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problems should arise, allocating an array of NSStrings is like making an array of the pointers to string objects. Pointers are a constant length. I would recommend just using NSArray but it is still fine to use a C array of NSStrings. Note that this may have changed with ARC.

Here is completely acceptable code demonstarting this:

```
NSString** array = malloc(sizeof(NSString*) * 10); // Array of 10 strings
array[0] = @"Hello World"; // Put on at index 0
NSLog(@"%@", array[0]); // Log string at index 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Since NSString is an object (and to be more precise: an *object cluster*) you cannot know its final size in memory, only Objective-C does. So you need to use the Objective-C allocation methods (like `[[NSString alloc] init]`), you cannot use `malloc`.

The problem is further that NSString is an *object cluster* which means you do not get an instance of `NSString` but a subclass (that you might not even know and should not care about). For example, very often the real class is `NSCFString` but once you call some of the methods that treat the string like a path you get an instance of `NSPathStore2` or whatever). Think of the `NSString` init methods as being factories (as in Factory Pattern).

**After question edit:**

What you really want is:

```
NSString **nssName;
nssName = (NSString**) malloc(iN * sizeof(NSString*));
```

And then something like:

```
nssName[0] = @"My string";
nssName[1] = [[NSString alloc] init];
...
```

This is perfectly fine since you have an *array of pointers* and the size of pointer is of course known.

But beware of memory management: first, you should make sure the array is filled with NULLs, e.g. with `bzero` or using `calloc`:

```
bzero(nssName, iN * sizeof(NSString*));
```

Then, before you `free` the array you need to `release` each string in the array (and make sure you do not store autoreleased strings; you will need to retain them first).

All in all, you have a lot more pitfalls here. You *can* go this route but using an `NSArray` will be easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

NSStrings can only be dealt with through pointers, so you'd just be making an array of pointers to NSString. Pointers have a defined length, so it's quite possible. However, an NSArray is usually the better option.

Answer (score 0):

You should `alloc`/`init...` the `NSString*`s or use the class's factory methods.  If you need an array of them, try `NSArray*`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use malloc to allocate data for Objective-C types. Doing this will allocate memory space but not much else. Most importantly the object will not be initialized, and almost as importantly the retain count for the object will not be set. This is just asking for problems. Is there any reason you do not want to use ***alloc*** and ***init***?